# Cached Java objects in C++ client

Tags: gemfire

I would like to have a C++ client application that maintains a cache of objects that come from a Java server. The objects need to be compatible. I understand that Gemfire maintains them in a serializable format. This means the Java class needs to be equivalent to the C++ class.

Is there a common practice for defining the class structure in common place in a language-independent specifcation and generating the equivalent Java and C++ classes that are serializable to PDX or any other form that Gemfire uses?

Regards,
Yash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before PDX I used to create a language-neutral representation of my domain and simultaneously generate Java, C++ and .Net classes using DataSerializable. However, PDX makes this unnecessary for the most part. I enclose the sample config below.

If you encounter types that you are using that Java does not support, you still do not have to resort to generating serializers but you can focus in on serializing that one type (see page 564 of http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/pdf/pivotal-gemfire-ug.pdf

Consider generating your own serializers when you have an insane need for speed since the auto-serializer can produce a drag. This is usually not needed but if you do, here are the instructions: http://data-docs-samples.cfapps.io/docs-gemfire/latest/javadocs/japi/com/gemstone/gemfire/DataSerializer.html

Here is the configuration for using the pdx auto serializer:

```
<!-- Cache configuration configuring auto serialization behavior -->
<cache>
 <pdx>
   <pdx-serializer>
     <class-name>com.gemstone.gemfire.pdx.ReflectionBasedAutoSerializer
     </class-name>
     <parameter name="classes">
       <string>com.company.domain.DomainObject</string>
     </parameter>
   </pdx-serializer>
 </pdx>
 ...
</cache>
```

If I answered your question, please give check "Answered".  Thanks.

Comment: If I have a class MyClass{ int myID; String myName } in Java, I cannot have MyClass{ String myName; int myID} in C++. They both need to match even with Auto PDX serialization. What language-neutral representation can I use to define the Java and C++ classes? I am more interested in getting the class structures right for both the languages. Speed of serialization is not a concern for me.

Comment: Given that specific, consider using your Java POJO as your server-side representation and then override your Employee PDXSerializer `toData` and `fromData` on the C++ native client to handle your different ordering and/ or types (see http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/gemfire_nativeclient/cpp-caching-api/using_pdxserializer.html).   If you must have language neutrality, store everything as a String and override the orders/ types in your serializers. To make it easy and automated, I have used code generators to gen the serializers from the objects metadata and make it all part of CI.

Comment: Can you suggest a code generator? Which one did you use?

Comment: I used an old IBM code generator that gen'd from XML to Java & C#. A team member thought it too complex and wrote code to generate the classes, which was easier to learn. If I had to do it again, I would keep it simple by using this approach: 1) Create my data object by copying the Java/ C++ templates (hashcode, equals, fromData, toData, etc methods). 2) Define annotations with name, from and to types - in the Java side. 3) Exec code that I write to generate the equals/ hashcode/ fromData/ toData. Yash, you can create that code for Geode and create the "common practice". Plz check answered. Ty